# A Good Algorithm for Counting Permutations Relating to a Pattern of Squares

Tags: permutations, algorithms

In the following table, each of the 43 rows must have *exactly* one gray square filled in, and each of the 33 columns must have *at least* one gray square filled in. My question is,
**what would be a good algorithm for counting how many permutations fulfill both of these requirements?**

My first thought would be to build a list of possibles row-by-row, and to test them for whether or not they meet the requirement for each column that has no more gray squares at lower rows. For example, only the permutations 11 (IH-IH), 12 (IH-KI), 13 (IH-IJ), 21 (HI-IH), and 31 (IJ-IH) fulfill the requirement for column IH. The requirement for column KI could test all possibilities through the fourth row, and so on. But this is still a far cry from a working algorithm, and I'm also worried that I may run into computing and memory problems.

Any insights would be appreciated. Also, please let me know what might make this problem clearer for you. I stripped out a lot to focus on the crux of my difficulties, as I see them.

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with graph theory?  If so, you can make a bipartite graph with $43+33$ vertices, one for each row and column, and with an edge for each gray square.  Then what you're looking for are (maximum cardinality) matchings in this graph.  Matching algorithms have been studied extensively, and the problem tends to be easier for bipartite graphs like this one.

Comment: Thanks, @RaviFernando, for the insights. My familiarity with graph theory could be described as piecemeal, at best. In any case, I'm working toward a solution using your suggestions. (See the as yet incomplete answer, below.) One point of confusion is that it seems matchings in bipartite graphs are supposed to be 1-to-1. But that doesn't work with the constraints I mentioned above. . . .

Comment: Ah, you're right--I must have misread "exactly" and "at least" as "at most" and "exactly" respectively.  (I see now that given my misreading, this could be calculated as the permanent of a one-padded Edmonds matrix--although even this may be too computationally expensive.)

I guess this will require a different idea.  I'll let you know if I think of anything.

Comment: @RaviFernando, glad you noticed those details and now appreciate the mess of a problem I'm trying to solve. BTW, I did my undergrad studies at Cal. I hope you're enjoying it despite the pandemic. I look forward to any more ideas you may have.

Answer (score 1):

Following Ravi's suggestion, one can more clearly represent this problem as a bipartite graph, which can further be reframed in terms of a flow network. To meet the constraints of this problem, all arrows at the left (from the source) and in the middle have a maximum flow of 1, and all arrows at the right (going to the sink/target) have a maximum flow of 11 (= 43 - 33 + 1).

Given the initial problem design, the maximum flow for this network, 43, is already known. The problem not-yet-solved is *how to count all possible flow paths.* Doing so efficiently is also important. (Full solution pending.)

[image: Problem Represented as a Flow Network Diagram]